# com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of Android stduio Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, spring-tool-suite

me sale ese error JsonObjectRequest está vacía. estoy  consumiendo de una web service a mi  app movil. he tratado de hacer un if con el response para ver si o no me trae el json pero no me resulta , les agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

el error :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo app kotlin
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo clase Datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask] para que entiendas como funciona el sitio. El código tiene que ir en formato de texto, ya que será mucho mas facil replicar tu escenario, y las imagenes puede ser que no todo el mundo las vea. Plusa en [edit] y mejora tu pregunta para que sea mejor bienvenida

Comment: Este error suele ocurrir cuando desde el servidor no mandas un json válido. Conviene que pongas el código de servidor con el que manejas esta petición Volley. Considera poner todo el código como texto, no capturas de pantalla.